# Can former expats in the NL keep their Dutch bank account if they move abroad and how do they pay taxes on interest?

Tags: taxes, netherlands, banking

I am an EU citizen. I lived in the Netherlands for a few years but left months ago. In a few weeks I'll be moving to another country outside of the EU.

I never closed my Dutch bank account. I like my bank, I'm happy with their service and their low fees. I have some savings (above 21K). I would like to keep using that account from abroad for as many years as possible, have my monthly income paid on that account etc. Can I do that if I'm not a Dutch national?

Also, how can I pay tax for the interest rates I get from my savings? Note that the last tax return I had to do was for the year 2016, and (I think) I don't have to do my taxes in the Netherlands again since I wasn't a resident after that.

Answer (score 1):

You can for sure keep your bank account even if you don't live in the Netherlands any more as long as your bank doesn't have any issues with a foreign address on the bank account. They will want to have an address of you where they could (at least theoretically) send smail mail to and IIUC they are even legally obliged to keep their customers address records updated.

But it's an entirely normal think for almost any bank to have foreign customers. And as banking is mostly online these days, you will have few practical problems.

About taxation: If you no longer live in the Netherlands, you will not be subject to taxation there any more. The bank may keep a so-called retention or withholding tax on the interest they pay you, so you may not receive 100% of your interest but only 80% or 75% in the first place. Usually you can claim the rest back, but the interest on 21K cannot be that much these days that it would be worth too much paperwork.

Comment: Dutch bank will ask for foreign tax number.